# How to print column1,column3 and column 9 to column12 of the csv using AWK command?

Tags: shell, awk

This below command prints 9-12 column of the csv files perfectly

```
grep -i introd *.csv | awk 'BEGIN { first = 9; last = 12 }{ for (i = first; i < last; i++) {printf("%s ", $i) } print $last }
```

but I also want to print the column1, column3 and column 30-35.

Comment: Please, post some sample data with the related expected output.
Don't post them as comments, images, tables or links to off-site
services but use text and include them to your original question.  Thanks.

Comment: Install the `csvkit` package and use `csvcut -c 1,3,9-12,30-35 foo.csv`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
grep -i introd *.csv | awk 'BEGIN { first = 9; last = 12 }{ print $1, $3 for (i = first; i < last; i++) {printf("%s ", $i) } print $last
```

Comment: it throws syntax error.

Comment: @himmat you're getting untested answers that include syntax errors because you didn't provide any sample input/output for us to test against. You're also getting downvotes and fewer people answering because of that, see [ask].

Answer (score 4):

With a small number of fields, it's easy to just do them explicitly, something like:

```
{ print $1","$3","$9","$10","$11","$12","$30","$31","$32","$33","$34","$35 }
```

That's the preferred solution if the number of fields is not too large.

---

If there *are* a larger number of fields (and you may, unlike me, consider twelve fields to be included in that), you can always create an associative array indicating *which* fields should be printed, including allowing for ranges like `n-m`. The code in this section of the answer illustrates that, by, first in the `BEGIN` section:

- splitting the `COLS` variable on commas, each element is either a single value or range.
- for each of those:

  - splitting on hyphens so that range bounds can be established.
  - if only one value, add that to the list of fields needed.
  - if more than one, use the first and second as inclusive bounds and add each field in that range.
- work out the lowest and highest field needed.

Then, in the per-input-line section:

- print out each field (from lowest to highest) if and only if it was one of the fields marked as needed.

The code to do that is:

```
BEGIN {
    split(COLS, ranges, ",")
    for (range in ranges) {
        split(ranges[range], values, "-")
        if (length(values) == 1) {
            use[values[1]] = 1
        } else {
            for (value = values[1]; value <= values[2]; value++) {
                use[value] = 1
            }
        }
    }

    hi = -1
    for (val in use) {
        if (hi  < 0) {
            lo = val
            hi = val
        } else if (val < lo) {
            lo = val
        } else if (val > hi) {
            hi = val
        }
    }
}
{
    sep = ""
    for (idx = lo; idx <= hi; idx++) {
        if (use[idx] == 1) {
            printf "%s%s", sep, $idx
            sep = ","
        }
    }
    print ""
}
```

This output shows how it works:

```
pax> echo 101 202 303 404 505 606 707 808 909 | awk -v COLS=2-4,7 -f myprog.awk
202,303,404,707
```

---

Just two notes. First, you cannot use that script to print *duplicates* of fields, such as `1-5,3-7`. I haven't allowed for that since there's nothing in your question to indicate that's a requirement but, if you *do* need that capability, you'll need to use a different method.

Second, it's likely to produce unexpected results or fail spectacularly if you do not provide a `COLS` or provide one that's not in the expected format. I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader if they wish to make it truly bullet-proof :-)

Neither of those points were addressed since I still maintain the first option presented is the best for you particular scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Generic solution, where you could pass a number of Ranges separated by `,` and range values should be separated by `-` within themselves. Also in case you want to pass multiple .csv file yes you can pass all of them like: `*.csv` to this program too.

```
awk -v range="9-12,30-35" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  num=split(range,arr,",")
}
{
  delete arr1
  value=""
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    split(arr[i],arr1,"-")
    for(start=arr1[1];start<=arr1[2];start++){
       value=(value?value OFS:"")$start
    }
  }
  print value
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk -v range="9-12,30-35" '         ##Starting awk program from here and setting range variable which has different ranges, in this case 9 to 12 AND 30 to 35 field numbers here.
BEGIN{                              ##Starting BEGIN section of this program from here.
  FS=OFS=","                        ##Setting FS and OFS as comma here.
  num=split(range,arr,",")          ##Splitting range to arr array with separator of comma here.
}
{
  delete arr1                       ##Deleting arr1 for safer side.
  value=""                          ##Nullifying value here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){              ##Running for loop till value of num here.
    split(arr[i],arr1,"-")          ##Splitting arr[i[ value into arr1 here with separator of - here.
    for(start=arr1[1];start<=arr1[2];start++){ ##Running for loop from arr[1] value to arr1[2] value.
       value=(value?value OFS:"")$start  ##Creating value which has fields value in it.
    }
  }
  print value                       ##printing value here.
}
'  Input_file                       ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this (untested due to no input/output provided to test against) should do it:

```
awk -v r='1 3 9-12 30-35' '
    BEGIN {
        numRanges = split(r,ranges)
        for (rangeNr=1; rangeNr<=numRanges; rangeNr++) {
            n = split(ranges[rangeNr],begEnd,/-/)
            for (inFldNr=begEnd[1]; inFldNr<=begEnd[n]; inFldNr++) {
                out2in[++numOutFlds] = inFldNr
            }
        }
    }
    {
        for (outFldNr=1; outFldNr<=numOutFlds; outFldNr++) {
            inFldNr = out2in[outFldNr]
            printf "%s%s", $inFldNr, (outFldNr<numOutFlds ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
' file
```

Comment: Sure, thank you for your thoughts sir, I have cleaned up the comment now, cheers.